# Preventing query to stay in pool

Tags: mysql

How can I prevent my finished queries to stay in pool?

Below is the image of my database and a lot of my finished queries are staying and I want them to be removed but don't know how.

[image: database image]

This is my code that I made to sent the data from my database using Express:

Here is my articles.js file that sends the data as json.

```
router.get('/articles', (req, res) => {
  let sql = "SELECT * FROM ARTICLES";
  myDB.query(sql, (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      res.send(results)
    }
  })
});
```

and this is my connection.js that creates the connection to MySQL and Express

```
    const mysql = require('mysql');
const myDB = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: 'REMOTE_DATABASE_ADDRESS',
    user: 'hmidev',
    password: 'hmidev',
    database: 'VD_NEW_WEBSITE'
});

myDB.getConnection((error, connection) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(`Successfully connected at VD_NEW_WEBSITE`);
    }
});

module.exports = myDB;
```

Comment: `myDB.end();`? Look https://stackoverflow.com/q/27386205/10138734 and similar

Comment: nope, it doesn't do what I want, it just kills the connection instantly

Comment: Connection is killed, but last query result is available nevertheless?

Comment: No it is not it kills the whole connection

Comment: If so try to execute some "empty" query (`SELECT 1;` for example, or `SELECT VERSION();`) - maybe it will override previous recordset? and add proper tag(s) (maybe [node.js] ?) to your question.

Comment: Does the page close the connection?  (What language are you writing in?  What is `myDB`?)  Is there "connection pooling" at any layer?  Other than clutter in `PROCESSLIST`, is there any real problem?

Comment: @RickJames myDB is the connection between MySQL and ExpressJS and for the page it does not close the connection and no other problems other than it stays at the pool

Answer (score 0):

Connections left in a connection pool will show up as "Sleep" in `PROCESSLIST`.  The "Time" will continue to grow until grabbed by a new "connect".